# Delete/Remove Powerpoint slide tag in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, tags, powerpoint

I have code to tag slides in a master PowerPoint file.

For example, I create smaller PowerPoint presentations based on tags of the master file (I can share the code if someone is interested). I have loops which go through all tags and I am afraid that the loop will take a very long time to execute in the future if tags are never removed.

```
Sub Newtag()

Dim slidename As String
slidename = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Name

Dim Newname As String

Newname = InputBox("Give new name")
If Trim(Newname) = "" Then Exit Sub
ActivePresentation.slides(slidename).Tags.Add "Tag", Newname

End Sub
```

I'd like to remove tags which I added.

Let's say that I want to remove the tag "Test tag" and slideindex 5.

I tried:

```
ActivePresentation.slides(5).Tags.Delete ("Test tag")

ActivePresentation.slides(5).Tags.Value(1).Delete

ActivePresentation.slides(5).Tags.Value("Test tag").Delete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> expression.Add (Name, Value)

Try this

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Tags.Delete ("TAG")
```

If you add using say,  `.Tags.Add "Andreas", "Sid"` then use

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Tags.Delete ("Andreas")
```

or simply loop and delete

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long

    With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
        .Tags.Add "Tag", "Sid"

        Debug.Print .Tags.Count

        For i = .Tags.Count To 1 Step -1
            .Tags.Delete (.Tags.Name(i))
        Next i

        Debug.Print .Tags.Count
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. That solved my problem, highly appreciated. I changed the .Tags.Delete (.Tags.Name(i)) to     .Tags.Delete (.Tags.Value(i)) in order to obtain the desired results. Cheers